# ¿Cómo puedo evitar que vuelva el valor NA cuando monto una correlación?

Tags: r, estadística

Puede parece sencillo, pero soy un aprendiz en R.
Quiero verificar la correlación entre dos variables con muchas observaciones.

```
cor(qog$bci_bci, qog$undp_hdi)
```

bci_bci y undp_hdi son las variables (bci la dependente): pero en ambas hay observaciones en "blanco" o con NA y cuando pido la correlación me sale el resultado (NA), cuanto hago con R2, lo mismo.

```
> cor(qog$bci_bci, qog$undp_hdi)^2
[1] NA
```

Answer (score 3):

Como primer estrategia habría que analizar la existencia de valores `NA` ¿Qué representan? ¿Cómo debemos considerarlos? ¿Podemos simplemente ignorarlos? Si de tu análisis se llega a la conclusión que corresponde hacer algo con ellos entramos en lo que se conoce como *imputación de valores faltantes* que es una disciplina que excedería el marco de una respuesta y da para un libro entero. Pero si tu idea es eliminarlos, puedes usar la función `na.ommit()` para quitar las filas que tengan algún `NA`:

```
# Aplicado a cualquier columna
qog_sin_na <- na.omit(qog)

# Aplicado solo a las columnas que vamos a correlacionar
qog_sin_na <- na.omit(qog[, c("bci_bci", "undp_hdi")])
```

Finalmente aplicarías la correlación al nuevo `data.frame`, ej: `cor(qog_sin_na$bci_bci, qog_sin_na$undp_hdi)^2`

Comment: Muchas gracias, en el modelo con más de una variable, he quitado las NA's y he hecho la comparación, todos los resultados son iguales (r2, p-value, etc); estoy buscando analisar la correlacion de una solo variable a la dependiente para mirar la fuerza de cada una y si no quiatra los NA, volvia solo este resultado. Pero eliminandoles como me has enseñado, si que tengo algo en manos para inferir.

Answer (score 2):

Una forma muy simple es usar el argumento `use = "pairwise.complete.obs"` en la función `cor()`. Con ese argumento se calcula la correlación solamente en aquellas filas en las que las dos columnas tienen valores válidos. El valor defecto es `use = "everything"` y en ese caso se conservan los `NA` y las operaciones aritméticas de `cor` los reciben y propagan. El resultado es que el coeficiente de correlación es `NA` siempre que haya al menos un valor `NA`.

La ventaja que le veo es que no necesitas crear (y rastrear) estructuras de datos adicionales.

En tu caso:

```
cor(qog$bci_bci, qog$undp_hdi, use = "pairwise.complete.obs")
```

En la ayuda de `cor` bajo el apartado Details puedes encontrar todas las opciones (bastante rudimentarias) para manejar casos perdidos con esta función. Lamentablemente no está traducida al español.

PD: suscribo plenamente el comentario de @Patricio Moracho sobre la importancia de diagnosticar los `NA` presentes en los datos. Eliminarlos es una solución técnicamente simple y en algunos casos analíticamente correcta. Pero conlleva el riesgo de introducir sesgos a los datos u omitir cuestiones importantes como que los `NA` provienen de un procesos generador de datos diferente a los datos válidos.